# Get static type of x in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have this class structure :

```
class A     {   }
class B:A   {   }

A x = new B();
```

this is the runtime type :

```
x.GetType(); //B
```

How can i get its *compile time* type  ?

I tried `typeof (x)` - but the argument has to be a type...

my desire answer is : `A`

### edit

why am i asking it ?

cause i think `int` is inistialized via `polymorphic` engine :

something like this :

```
object myInd = new Int32(); / /this DOES compile
```

and i want to verify my assumption :

does  it come from object  ?

and in order to do it - i have to know its static type....

Comment: Look to the left of the x.

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context? I fail to see a use-case for this, since the compile-time type is always known to the developer...

Comment: @HansPassant Hans , I already know that. i just want the answer via code...

Comment: @HansPassant read my edit please.:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know in C# code which type a variable was declared with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786750/how-to-know-in-c-sharp-code-which-type-a-variable-was-declared-with)

Comment: @Heinzi: The type is not always known to the developer. Consider `var` variable assigned to by a function. Although you can check the function return type, you don't always want to depend on that.

Comment: @Dani var is baking its type in compile time....

Comment: I understand what you're asking, but not why.  Usually all you need to care about is what the variable is at run time, e.g. `x is B`.  I don't see where you should code differently depending on whether the caller has `A x = new B();` or `B x = new B();`.

Comment: You need to read about boxing/unboxing (see my answer)

Comment: @jeroenh see my comment to your answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a generic method:

```
Type StaticTypeOf<T>(T t)
{
  return typeof(T);
}
```

To call it:

```
object i = 1;

// Writes out System.Object
Console.WriteLine(StaticTypeOf(i).ToString());
```

It's a solution - even though I don't see what the problem solved with the solution is ;-)

Comment: Actually you dont need `...(T t)`!

Comment: Then you'd have to say `StaticTypeOf<object>()`, which defeats the purpose you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Correct but hardly useful... You're just using the compiler feature of type inference to tell you what you already know - that `i` is of type `object`.

Comment: @jeroenh: I don't understand the use for this either, but apparently Royi Namir has a use for it so I helped him with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments by others - the static type of an object is something you tell the compiler yourself, at compile time. There is absolutely no point in finding it out at runtime.

```
object myInd = new Int32(); / /this DOES compile
```

This compiles not because "int is initialized via a polymorphic engine", but because in C# everything can be converted to type `object`. This is not the same.

The conversion from a value type (such as `Int32`) to `object` is realized through the process of `boxing`. You can read all about it on this msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx.

Comment: you didnt understand my question at all !. ok it is a boxed value. i know that. but when i  write `object i=5` and later `i.Equals(3)` - the equals is resolved at RUNTIME via virtual function from the object ! so the chain starts from object downto int32... the equlas can  be started at `int i=5;` and also `object i=5` - but the chain in the former will start at the object level and in the latter it will start from `int`. i needed to check that.

Comment: Indeed everything incl. value types is derived from System.Object, but that has nothing to do with the compile time type. My answer stands: the compile time type is what you write yourself, there is no point in finding it out at runtime. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436211/is-everything-in-net-an-object/436246